# springframework.security package not found with starter-security dependency?

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-security, dependency-management

I'm using ***spring boot*** and *spring starter dependencies* for my project. 
I tried with spring starter security dependency in ***Gradle***, but only security packages are not found in project. IDE is *IntelliJ IDEA*‎.

My ***build.gradle*** file :

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.2.7.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}") 
        classpath('io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.2.RELEASE')
        classpath("org.springframework:springloaded:1.2.4.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot' 
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management' 

jar {
    baseName = 'hashfon-spring'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mustache')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')

    runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') 
}
```

All libraries except security can be found in ***External Libraries***...

One example of class in project:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.*;
import org.springframework.hateoas.*;
import org.springframework.mock.*;
import org.springframework.data.*;
import org.springframework.security.*;  //cannot resolve symbol!
/**
 * I can import all packages from external libraries except security
 */
```

PS. I tried with a lot of different release versions of *spring-security-core* and nothing happens.

Comment: Is that your actual import statement?

Comment: @M.Deinum yes, yes.. security subfolder cannot be found :/

Comment: Is that REALLY your import statement? As currently it is illegal and won't even compile because it is missing `.*;`....

Comment: @M.Deinum yes I edited that

Comment: @M.Deinum There is no syntax problem. I have problem cause my gradle project cannot see security libraries and classes...

Comment: Did you reimport dependencies?

Comment: @jny i redownloaded all dependencies.. deleted gradle cache folder and downloaded them again...

Comment: But did you do it in a project? with maven, there is an option to reimport dependencies... Probably there is one with gradle as well...

Comment: Go to View ->Tool Windows ->Gradle. Click on the left most button (Refresh). This might take awhile.

Comment: @jny GREAT! Refresh button on Gradle tool window helped. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After dealing with this issue multiple times I came across following solution which works for me 100%:

1. Go to *File | Invalidate Caches*
2. Delete folder where all dependencies are stored (***~/.gradle/*** for UNIX systems) - if it exists after invalidation
3. Restart Intellij IDEA
4. Reimport gradle dependencies by refreshing gradle:
   [image]

Comment: This worked for me without step 2 or 4. Thank you!