# springframework.security package not found using spring-boot-starter-security

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-security

I am having [exact same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33416667/springframework-security-package-not-found-with-starter-security-dependency) but using maven

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/3.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/3.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-3.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sales</groupId>
    <artifactId>Sales</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>FinalProjV1</name>
    <description>Sales Application</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Unable to import `org.springframework.security.*`.

But if I check in the maven repository it is downloaded

[image: Spring-Boot-Security is present]

Also the jar is present in Java Build Path

[image: Java Build Path]

Comment: The starter itself contains nothing but a pom with dependencies to spring security. make sure those are downloaded. Do a `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` and then try again.

Comment: I ran `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` command. It downloaded all the dependencies again, But no luck.

Comment: Ehrm that won't download anything, it will wipe your repository. After that you will have to do a `mvn package` to re-download the dependencies.

Comment: Well I ran `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` then `mvn package`. It worked for me. What's the science behind this ?

Comment: Could be a borked dependency, purging the repository forces a download of the dependencies again.

Answer (score 3):

Worked for me after closing the project and reopening